# How to find 5 biggest elements in extremely big array optimally

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have an extremely big array. I have to find the top 5 biggest elements in that array. What could be the best/optimal algorithm to do this?

**Please note that I don't have to do sorting and it's an unsorted array**

Comment: Use a heap of size 5 and put elements on that heap if they are bigger than the smallest one (and remove that).

Comment: Look into the selection algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: @JonH The selection algorithm is `O(n)` but with complex code and horrible constants.  If you're looking for `m` elements in an unsorted array of `n` things with `n` much larger than `m`, the heap solution that Nico suggested is going to be much, much faster in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the array is unsorted the most efficient algorithm is to iterate through the list and store your 5 biggest elements in a `SortedList`. When the current element in the iteration is bigger than the smallest one (first element in `SortedList`), you remove the smallest element and add the current element to the list. It complexity will be `O(n)`.

Comment: It's complexity would be how much  ?

Comment: O(n) complexity as you go exactly one time through the array of length n

Comment: Its complexity will be `O(n)`

Comment: Again read about the selection algorithm its Big O(n) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm